# swift .contains with strings working but with error

Tags: swift

I have a playground code that works but it gives an error at the same time. I'm not too sure why cause I'm not too familiar with swift.

I wanted to write an if statement below that will check if junior has the suffix "Jr."

```
if junior.contains("Jr.") {
    print("We found a second generation name!")
}else{
    print("No we didn't find a second generation name.")
}
```

And I used .contains method -- though it gives me an error like below.
[image]

Comment: You need `import UIKit`, `import Foundation` or `import Cocoa`.

Comment: ya I imported Foudnation

Comment: Did you spell it right? :)  BTW, there is `if junior.hasSuffix("Jr.")`.

Comment: o ya I spelt it wrong / overlooked it for past hour lol thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed with

```
import Foundation
```